# Does a project need to be a 100% completed with domain name, ssl setup, logo before requesting review from facebook?

Tags: .net, facebook, azure

I'm using .net and hooked up my app to azure.

In my fb developer account i've got a "myproject" app that sits on the dashboard and below that "myproject-testing" for debugging purposes.
From my local machine it posts a photo to facebook using the "myproject-testing" appId and appSecret. But it won't do it from azurewebsites.net using the same appId and secret. I've configured azure appropriately with the faceook authentication. I'm not sure if that is expected with the testing appId and appSecret.

I haven't hooked up a registered domain yet.

On azure the ajax request throws an internal server error when I try and post but if I comment out

//client.Post("me/photos", parameters);

the ajax request returns success.

Thanks.

Comment: Quite the discrepancy between title and question content ... regarding the former - no, but you must present a working version, and it should look at least half-way presentable to an end user (because that's the people you eventually request the review for.) But your actual "question" (please go read [ask], btw.) sounds like you're still a bit a way from a working version even ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On azure the ajax request throws an internal server error

According to the exception, it seems that code error during run it on the azure.
As you mentioned that it works correctly on local machine. I assume that it maybe the photo can't be found in the azure environment.

If you are using Azure WebApp, you could [remote debug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) your code with Visual Studio.

I do a C# Asp.net demo and publish it to azure, it works correctly on my side.

The following is my test demo.

1.Create an Asp.net project and reference the [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) SDK

2.Add a image file named images.jpg to project root path

3.Add the follow code to Page_load

```
   var accessToken = "access token";
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "images.jpg";
    var imgstream = File.OpenRead(path);
        dynamic res = client.Post("/me/photos", new
        {
            file = new FacebookMediaStream
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpg",
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(path)
            }.SetValue(imgstream)
        });
```

4.Test it on the local machine.

[image]

5.Publish it to Azure and I can get the posted photo from facebook page.

[image]